# Two word domain name for ecommerce website with .shop ending or .com with hyphen between

Tags: e-commerce, branding

I have a two word brand name and building an ecommerce website. Unfortunately the .com domain without a hyphen between the words is already taken - a small company from china. So i registered the .shop (without hyphen) and the .com with a hyphen between. I already applied for trademark protection in my home country - far away from China :)

My question - should i opt for the onetwo.shop or the one-two.com domain. At the moment i lean towords .shop

Comment: I would lean towards shop as well. It's easier to remember than a hyphen, it's easier to type on a phone, and if I lost people to the other site by mistaken typing, I would rather have to correct them about shop than about placing a hyphen. Also, for now it's still novel and eye-catching.

Comment: Thx for you input @LukeSawczak - makes tottaly sense

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider and register onetwoshop.com and/or getonetwo.com (good for specific product/service) for protective purposes. Alias the domains to redirect to whichever you choose anyways, and consider running some A/B testing with adwords or social media posts to see which your target market respond to better.

Comment: I was about to mention the same thing! `onetwoshop.com` is better than hyphen or `.shop`.

Comment: Also 12shop.com 

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience back in college where we started a small freelance group and had a portfolio website for that. We decided 'Innovative Bug' as the name but we couldn't find the right domain:

- innovative-bug.com : We purchased this and started using this since it had a global presence because of .com
- innovativebug.in : We also purchased this (.in is for Indian domains) but we didn't use this as it didn't seem global.

When we started getting a few clients, we asked them to refer to our website for any of the details and we had to explain to them at least twice how to spell the domain name. Later we realised it's easier to use the '.in' domain as it was just convenient to have a domain which didn't have any special characters in it.

Comment: Thx for your feedback. best